# Doctrine2 and phpunit detach give Null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have something I don't understand with my entity manager during my tests.

I'm in my phpunit testEntityClass.php

```
$entity = $this->em->find(4);
var_dump( get_class ($entity) ); // Class Entity -> ok
$entity = $this->em->detach($entity );
var_dump($entity ); //Null -> wtf
var_dump( get_class ($entity) ); // Class PhpEntityTest, seems legit since entity is now totally null
```

Any idea ?

I can't even print `the var_dump($entity );` before the `detach()` It display a surprising ammount of information, Even metadata about entities its not related are attached to the entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `detach` returns nothing (which means it always returns `null`). You've got `PhpEntityTest` in thrid `var_dump` because `get_class(null)` always gives you name of current class.